# Google Script Javascript Prevent date entry if cell changed to blank

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a budget spreadsheet for myself and one of the things I want it to do is fill in the paid date when I mark paid with todays date. I have the script working for that however, if I remove that it is paid, it keeps the date.

I decided to print todays date if the field was changed. But I can't seem to get my if to work with an and in it. What am I missing here?

```
function onEdit(e) {
   if ([9, 13, 17, 21].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1 
      && [9, 13, 17, 21].indexOf(e.range.getValue) != "") {
   e.range.setValue(new Date());
  }
 }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to be able to see an example spreadsheet.  Are marking paid in the same column as you want the date?

Comment: Yes. I am using conditional formatting to change the color of text and background in the cell upon entry of any value. When any value is written it should then overwrite with the date (which it does). The problems come when I try to clear the value of that field. It counts it as still being edited (because of the on edit function) and drops the date back in to the field. It ignored the fact that I am telling it to only write the date if the the cell is not blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this to work if I used validation in columns 9,13,17,21 with list items of `Paid,Not Paid`.  I also added a Sheet Name so that it will only happen on one sheet.  That may be something you don't want...not sure.  I also offset the writing of the data to one column to the right.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('1 ' + e.value);
  if ([9,13,17,21].indexOf(e.range.columnStart)!=-1 && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='Sheet1' && e.value.toLowerCase()=="paid" ) {
    //e.source.toast('2');
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
  }
  if ([9,13,17,21].indexOf(e.range.columnStart)!=-1 && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='Sheet1' && e.value.toLowerCase()!="paid" ) {
    //e.source.toast('3');
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue('');
  }
}
```

Here's what my column 9 looks like:

[image]